# Protect data validation from deletion but let it still be changed

Tags: validation, checkbox, google-sheets, dropdown

I am trying to protect my checkboxes and dropdown lists in a way that other user arent able to delete the cell but can still change the value of the checkbox.

Is that possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this is not possible. edit rights include the right to edit/set the cell to be empty.

best you can do is to set up some color alert if a cell becomes empty like:

[image: 0]